# dealing with numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

this code is an example for adding two numbers input by user,it works fine if the numbers entered by the user less than 10 i.e 5 and 4 but it it results in ascii charachter if:

- the numbers entered by the user greater than or equal to 10 i.e. 6 and 12.
- or if the sum of two digits is greater than 10 i.e. 5 and 5.

what is the problem in the code bellow so it can accept any decimal i.e. 400+650

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4

STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data 

msg1 db "Enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD 
len1 equ $- msg1 

msg2 db "Please enter a second digit", 0xA,0xD 
len2 equ $- msg2 

msg3 db "The sum is: "
len3 equ $- msg3

segment .bss

num1 resb 2 
num2 resb 2 
res resb 1    

section .text
global _start    ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:    ;tell linker entry point
 mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
 mov ebx, STDOUT         
 mov ecx, msg1         
 mov edx, len1 
 int 0x80                

 mov eax, SYS_READ 
 mov ebx, STDIN  
 mov ecx, num1 
 mov edx, 2
 int 0x80            

 mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
 mov ebx, STDOUT         
 mov ecx, msg2          
 mov edx, len2         
 int 0x80

 mov eax, SYS_READ  
 mov ebx, STDIN  
 mov ecx, num2 
 mov edx, 2
 int 0x80        

 mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
 mov ebx, STDOUT         
 mov ecx, msg3          
 mov edx, len3         
 int 0x80

 ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
 ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
 mov eax, [number1]
 sub eax, '0'
 mov ebx, [number2]
 sub ebx, '0'

 ; add eax and ebx
 add eax, ebx
 ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
 add eax, '0'

 ; storing the sum in memory location res
 mov [res], eax

 ; print the sum 
 mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
 mov ebx, STDOUT
 mov ecx, res         
 mov edx, 1        
 int 0x80 exit:    
 mov eax, SYS_EXIT   
 xor ebx, ebx 
 int 0x80
```

Comment: For to get some ASCII values using the base ten number system we have in the first step to substract "0" from the ASCII and the next step we have to multiplicate the digits example by ten, by hundred and by thousend and in the last step we can add the values together to the first value.

Answer (score 0):

What your program actually does is:

- Read in four bytes.
- Take the first and the third byte entered from keyboard. If you enter two one-digit numbers you'll have the two digits (because the second byte is the "return" key)
- Subtract the ASCII code of '0' from both characters. If the two characters are digits you'll get the decimal value - otherwise you'll get rubbish
- Add the two numbers; then add the ASCII code of '0'. If the sum was less than 10 then the result is the ASCII code of the digit 0-9; otherwise it is some other ASCII code.
- Print out the character

Try adding any number while the first (leftmost) digits of the first one are 123 (Example: Add 12345 and 678). You'll see that the result is always 4 because the first character entered by keyboard is '1' and the third one is '3'.

To output a number >= 10 you'll have to use the "div" instruction: The "div cl" instruction - for example - will divide the 16-bit (unsigned) number in ax (the low 16 bits of eax) by the value in cl (the low 8 bits of ecx) and place the quotient (rounded down) into al (low 8 bits of eax) and the remainder in ah (high 8 of low 16 bits of eax).